# What is the semantic equivalent of label/input tags for read-only data?

Tags: html

In HTML forms input fields and their captions are declared as `label` and `input` tags, but which tags should be used for *displaying* the same data?

I'm considering either `dl`, `dt`, `dd` or `label` and disabled `input` tags, but both solutions don't feel right.

Of course there are many ways to "somehow" display the data, but I was wondering if there's a preferred way to do this.

Comment: If it's solely for presentation imho there's no real point in using form elements. What about <span class="form-data">Data</span> and style it to your liking.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this depends on what the data *is* and how you'd describe it.

If you're showing a list of titles with associated reference data then a definition list seems to fit the bill. (Since it retains the semantic link between title and reference data).

This will be similar in how the label is directly linked to your form fields using the `for` attribute, making it not just about visual reference but also about data connection and relation.

I usually ask myself the question, "What am I trying to say here?" and "How do my data relate to one another".

Answer (score 4):

Bear in mind that label/input is just a user-adjustable variation of the notion of key/value (or name/value) pairs. What you want is merely something that represents a key (label) and value (text) in such a way that the two can be distinguished from each other. The input performs the "value" function visually, and forces the user to regard the label as the name of the value. Without the visual clue of the input you can still make the name/value relationship obvious by bolding the name, putting it in a different color, different font, spacing, etc.

Even if you were to use `<dd>` and `<dt>` and the like, you would still need to make sure the name/value distinction was visually distinctive. (Especially if you were using a reset stylesheet that canceled out any inherent browser-generated difference between the tags.)